# Which app was removed by iOS 10 update?

Tags: iphone, ios

When updating from iOS 9 to iOS 10 on an iPhone 6S Plus, I noticed an app icon disappearing from a custom folder with all the iOS native apps inside. I couldn't remember which one it was, and some serious googling didn't reveal anything, either. I have a sneaking suspicion that it has something to do with HomeKit/Home.

Does anyone know for sure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right Christian, I didn't even notice it but the gamecenter app has been removed.
It is stated under gamekit in the IOS 10.0 [releasenotes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS10.html)

Apparently it won't be missed by many :)

Comment: Thank you :) Great resource you linked to, how could google not come up with that in the first place ...